# GoogleJsonResponseException 403 Forbidden PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using google REST Api to retrieve list of spreadsheets.
Everything works when it is accessed by my account.

But when I try to use foreign account, I'm getting this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden {
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "The caller does not have permission",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "The caller does not have permission",
"status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

It says I have no access to my google script, but the script is set as visible and shared for anyone.

Code:

```
    private Object getDataFromApi(ExecutionRequest request)
            throws IOException
    {

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            request.setDevMode(true); // it will take saved version of script and not the published one
        }

        // Make the request.
        Operation op =
                mService.scripts().run(SCRIPT_ID, request).execute();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem was in code:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    request.setDevMode(true); // it will take saved version of script and not the published one
}
```

It looks like it alway force to access saved version and not the published. Then the foreign account had no access to saved version and returns error 403.

When I disable this dev mode or install release version, then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SCOPE from SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY to SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS.

private static final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);